# Transações completadas com falhas devem persistir no banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, acid

Ao deparar-me com essa afirmação eu fiquei confuso, alguém poderia esclarecer?

> **Pergunta**: Uma das propriedades conhecidas em banco de dados relacionais como ***ACID*** é a durabilidade, segundo a qual, em uma transação completada com sucesso, todas as atualizações feita no banco por essa transação devem persistir.
>
> > **(1)** Exceto se houver outras transações em execução no momento da falha.
> >
> > **(2)** Mesmo na ocorrência de falhas no sistema de banco de dados, após o termino da transação.

A afirmação **(1)** ou **(2)** ou **ambas** estão corretas? Qual seria a justificativa?

Caso seja a afirmação **(2)**, realizar persistência de transações falhas não viola a a propriedade "**C**" referente a consistência?

Para mais informações a respeito do questionamento, posto aqui a origem da indagação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi o negativo

Comment: Eu também não =(

Comment: Só posso especular sobre o negativo. A introdução fala em transação completada com sucesso e as proposições falam em falhas, isso não faz sentido.

Comment: @Maniero na sua opinião os Screens servem de melhoria para a questão?

Comment: De fato é a D, mas é discutível na forma como foi colocado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A durabilidade é uma propriedade que deve ser garantida em todas as vezes que a transação é completada, não importa o que ocorra fora da transação. Então a D é a correta.

A transação só se completa de fato após ela ter se tornado durável, ou seja, persistida. É óbvio que se ocorrer um problema após todas operações necessárias se completarem e antes da durabilidade se completar, o ACID não se cumprirá.

Mas é questionável a forma como foi colocada, dá margem para interpretação, parece que a persistência não faz parte da transação.